# Lower Bound of Inner Product if norms are bounded

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, triangles, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $F = \sup d(x,y)$ where $x ,y \in A$.

I came across a problem where it was given that if $ \|a\| < F$ , $ \|b\| < F$. Then $ -F^2/4 < a \bullet b < F^2 $ for any $a,b \in A$. I know the upper bound comes from the Cauchy Schwartz inequality. Can someone tell me the proof of the lower bound. Thanks

Comment: Where is it from? This seems.. wrong. (namely, take $a=-b$...)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had not defined F properly. Now i have edited and defined properly.

Comment: I assume here $d(x,y)$ is the $\ell_2$ distance $\lVert x-y\rVert_2$?

Comment: Yes. It is. Would you know the solution in that case?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, but again, have you tried *anything*? Getting a lower bound of $-F^2/2$, for instance, seems very easy.

Comment: I don't see how your edit helps.

Answer (score 2):

This fails in one dimension. Let $a = 2/3$ and $b = -2/3$ and $F = 1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had not defined F properly. Now i have edited and defined properly.